# Autoload with namespaces in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

How do you use _autoload in PHP 5.3 with namespaces? I have a main autoload function in a namespace separate from my script. I'm also calling a class with a different namespace. (It's not surprising, but) It's not finding the autoload function. Do I have to recreate the autoload function for each namespace? That seems suboptimal.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From a comment in [the PHP manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php):

> To use autoload function with
>   namespaces you should remember to
>   define it in main scope in "\"
>   namespace.

Comment: Well, that was simple. Works like a charm.

Thanks! I'd vote the answer up, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @M3Mania, you can mark the answer as accepted. There's a little check image right below the down-vote arrow.