# Problems with Autoloader which autodetects classes

Tags: php, autoload

I'm currently programming on my Framework in PHP (mainly for education reasons, and a way of passing time). And I wrote an Autoloader which automatically scans the directory tree and detects all the classes in it and creates an array in the following format:

```
Array(
    'MyAwesomeClass' => 'path/to/file/in/some/subdirectory/MyAwesomeClass.php',
    'MyOtherAwesomeClass' => 'path/to/file/MyOtherAwesomeClass.php'
     // ....
);
```

At first this was very neat. Because i don't needed to worry where I put my classes.

But later I discovered this is very resource intense. So I created an cache mechanism and the index is serialized and saved to a file. This decreased the response time of the PHP-Script by at least 50%. But it brought some issues with it.

In other classes in the framework I often use things like:

```
class_exists('MyAwesomeClassController');
```

The problem is if I added the new class `MyAwesomeClassController` the class is not yet in the index and `class_exists` returns false. The problem now is I have to delete the cached file (to let the autoloader recreate the index again) every time I add a new class to the Framework.

Another thing I tried (which is a bit hacky):
In the Autoloader class I checked if the auto load method was called using class_exists(). If this was the case I recreated the Index to see if I can find the requested class somewhere. But this doesn't seem to work out as well because sometimes `class_exists` is called using a class which mostly doesn't exists, so this is basicly the same solution as recreating the index on every request.

Any solutions? Or do I have to rewrite my Autoloader completely?

Comment: what happens when you move a class? How to invalid the cache?

Comment: If i move a class to an other directory the index needs to be recreated and the cache would be invalid. The cache would also be invalid if a added, or deleted a class.

Comment: What you try to do already exists! Take a Look at: https://github.com/theseer/Autoload. You have the possibility to build an autoload.php file. It is easy to integrate it to your Deployment with ANT...

Comment: @MarkusI. I'll definitely take a closer look at it.

Comment: @MarkusI. I took a short look at it. This doesn't solve my problem. If I add a class i have to run `$ phpab`. This would basicly be the same as  if i execute `$ rm my-cache-file`

Answer (score 1):

I went this path a time ago, and came to the same conclusion: to resource intensive. What you are actually doing here is building some kind of linker.

I switched to a combination of namespaces and a map. I map a namespace to a folder and when the autoloader is called, it strips of the namespace, looks up the corresponding folder, and includes the file.

my map looks like this (I choose xml for the format) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<autoloader>  
  <namespace id="Ganymedes\Core">/system/core</namespace>
  <namespace id="Ganymedes\Core\Debug">/system/core/debug</namespace>
</autoloader>
```

And the class loader:

```
  public function ClassLoader( $class )
  {    
    if( class_exists( $class, false ))
      return true;

    $classparts = explode( '\\', $class );
    $classfile = '/' . strtolower( array_pop( $classparts )) . '.php';
    $namespace = implode( '\\', $classparts );

    if( isset( $this->namespaces[$namespace] )) {
      foreach ( $this->namespaces[$namespace] as $path ) 
        if( is_readable( $path . $classfile ))
          include_once $path . $classfile;

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Comment: the problem is I don't use many namespaces in my project to keep the calls short & simple. But this would be a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I haven't understood properly what you are trying to do... but what is wrong with `get_include_path`/`set_include_path` and the `__autoload($class)` built in function?

EDIT to explain my comment:

In "header.php" (file which gets included at the start of every script):

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR."my/first/directory"
                                   .PATH_SEPARATOR."my/second/directory"
                                   .PATH_SEPARATOR."this/is/another/directory"
                                   ...
                                   .PATH_SEPARATOR."and/here/is/the/last/one");

function __autoload($class) {
    require_once($class.".class.php");
}
```

The autoload function checks each directory in the path, until it finds the required file. I've never checked it for performace, but I'm guessing that it is fairly insignificant unless you have 100s of directories. If you are organised, you can put your frequently used (base) classes in the first "extra" path so that they are found immediately.

I've just noticed in the PHP manual online that __autoload is no longer advised, and that spl_autoload_register should be used instead, but the concept is the same.

Comment: I don't think you understood it. I'm having issues when autoloading, because it's either too slow, or inconvenient.

Comment: It appears that I haven't understood it at all then... if you don't mind my asking, could you explain it? What I wrote above seems to work fine for me... I set the include path to include my directory structure, and use the autoload function to load the classes. I don't see any particular slowness, and once I've set the include path I don't need to do anything else.

Comment: The include path is not an issue. I have a quite large folder structure containing PHP-Classes. My Autoloader scans this folder recursively and puts all the classes found into an array so if later the a class is needed the autoloader knows the exact position and the autoloader only needs to include the file. The scanning is very resource intense, so I tried to cache the location of the classes. But this doesn't work out well.

Comment: Well... you've certainly confused me. I do it like this: I change the include path to contain my directory structure, and create a function __autoload($class) at the start of my script. Every time a class is required, the __autoload() function is called automatically with the class name, and the class gets loaded. As long as you take care not to duplicate class names it seems to work fine. As long as the directory structure is in the include path, you'll never miss a class. I've never felt the need to change this setup, and I have hundreds of classes in my framework, spread across many folders

Comment: from where does your __autoload function know in which folder the requested class is?

Comment: Updated my previous answer. I would guess that for small to medium frameworks this solution would be reasonable.

Comment: This doesn't work out if you have classes with the same name in different namespaces, but the idea is good +1

Comment: I think with a small tweak it can be made to work with namespaces: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354944/autoload-with-namespaces-in-php-5-3). Cheers, Gareth

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that the classes you're trying to load should always exist, your autoloader could do the following:

1. Look up the class name inside the map (which is cached). If it exists, load the file.
2. If it doesn't exist, perform another scan and look up the class name in the newly generated map. If it exists, write the new map to disc and load the file.
3. If it still doesn't exist, raise the alarm.

The third step could be improved by introducing a negative cache as well; if the class is present in that map, you know the class doesn't exist based on a previous attempt. The negative cache would be shorter lived but just long enough to not trash your server.

You could also consider creating the cache offline as part of a deployment system.

Comment: I already tried the 3 steps you suggested here, but a negative list would be a relatively good solution. Thank you for that :-)

Comment: After thinking a bit more about it the negative cache still wouldn't solve my problem. It wouldn't recreate the index if a created a class which is in the negative cache. And this happens sometimes ...

Comment: @mogria the negative cache would have a shorter refresh rate and besides, it's short lived because it's a bug right? So you'd fix it quickly right? :)